# How can I ask my manager to reduce threats of disciplinary action from our director?

Tags: communication, work-environment

People in this scenario:

- Me - lowly employee
- Boss - manager of employees
- Director - Boss's boss, head of department

Recently, I started a new job. Since then, I've noticed that nearly every interaction I have with Boss (either one-on-one or in group meetings), he mentions that we better do or not do something or Director will verbally reprimand us or even terminate us.

To the best of my knowledge, neither I nor anyone I know personally has done anything particularly wrong. The threats are usually framed as "we better get [project] done or Director will yell at us" or "we better not do [bad workplace practice] or Director will have our jobs." Boss has mentioned on multiple occasions that Director has yelled at him in private and threatened to fire people, and he has mentioned repeatedly that he's "just trying to protect [us] from Director."

This has left me feeling incredibly demoralized and intimidated in this job. How can I bring up to my boss to let him know gently that these constant warnings feel threatening and are hurting morale (at least for me) without sounding confrontational or disrespectful? Or should I just not bother and get out of there?

Comment: Sorry about the dupes, not sure how those got posted. I've deleted them.

Comment: Stuff happens, don't worry about it :)

Comment: How about just gnoring the drama and getting the project done so no level of management is inclined to yell at anyone? Outside of that. you can try telling you manager that everyone knows failing to execute can cost jobs and the repetition serves no purpose... But unless _their_ manager tells them this, they may not listen. If you do decide to move, remember that moving within a company so you're under a different manager may also be an option.

Comment: @baphomet Have you ever personally experienced such situation? (failing to do certain thing and being yelled/someone fired?). Or is this "something your boss *said*"

Comment: This may just be a bad boss's attempt to encourage people -- or a good boss's bad attempt. The Director may not have any idea this is being said... If the director is not you boss's immediate boss, a skip-level interview with your second line manager may not be inappropriate, to ask about how seriously to take this.

Comment: At least in the USA, the job market is very much in favor of the individual workers.  Companies don't have the leverage to threaten someone's job because there are plenty out there. I wouldn't be averse to telling your boss this directly, and saying if he keeps up this attitude he's not going to have a team much longer.

Comment: Opinion: this is a very weak leadership style from Boss. I gather from your description this isn't an accurate reflection of what you have heard or seen from director.

Comment: I'll bet you a donut that the Director hasn't said these things and that they are originating from your manager who's using the Director as a shield. I'm a boss, I allow my people to "blame" me for things where they need to, but only externally.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR - Take the idea, reject the drama.**

Listen to what idea your boss has to offer for improvement / betterment, but ignore the part where the specific "threats" are involved.

This is true for any job, that if you do not do your job well, you are to be replaced, sooner or later. Some people are just bad at expressing things, try to look past that (at least, for now).

Of course, if you experience the scenarios in real life (firsthand or otherwise) - then that's a serious things to worry about. Yelling / shouting has no place in a professional work environment. Given that the referred to "Director" is the head, unless you're in a medium to large company with a proper HR organisation in place, it's very unlikely that you can raise a complaint, and /or the behaviour is going to change. In other words, probably it'll be a good time to find a new workplace (that may end up changing jobs).

Answer (score 1):

**The question as titled - "How can I ask my manager to reduce threats of disciplinary action from our director?"**

Just ask. It sounds like you and your direct boss have a decent working relationship. If you have regular 1 to 1's then raise it during that, otherwise get a few minutes of their time to raise it specifically. As long as you are factual and not confrontational about it, there is little they can say negatively about it. Something as simple as "Hi Boss, I have to be honest and say I really struggle when I hear that the Director wants to fire us all the time, I find it quite difficult to cope with".

That being said this does come with something of a health warning, and this comes from my own experience of working in such an environment...

**Don't expect things to change**

Directors who think the way to get the best of people is to keep them in a constant state of fear for their jobs are not normally the kind of people who listen to feedback or ever see the need to change. That you feel nervous or uncomfortable is likely what the Director wants because in their opinion "if you're nervous for your job, you'll work harder". If you do speak to your Boss about this and they take it to the Director, there is the potential that the Director, rather than taking it as something they need to work on, will see it as confirmation their strategy is working.

**So what can you do?**

Well you've not been at the organisation long. It is possible that this is a short term situation brought about by stress on the Directors part (stress does really weird things to people), so it may be worth giving it a chance and seeing if things settle down. Maybe speak with your new colleagues and find out if the Director is always like this. If it is the case that this is 'normal' for this workplace, then you need to decide if you can work in this kind of corporate culture. Some people thrive on pressure, some don't. There is no prize for being the former, nor shame for being the latter. If you decide ultimately this place is not a good fit for you, then it's time to look elsewhere. That, however is something you need to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Call our their unprofessionalism**

The threats themselves are unprofessional and the actions themselves would be VERY unprofessional.

Has any actual yelling occurred yet? Did you have any interactions with the director so far and how did they go? Could be that your boss is just trying to scare you (which is IMO a stupid thing to do). Could be that the director is actually doing these things.

Either way, it's unprofessional and an unhealthy work environment. Ask your boss

**Does the director really think that yelling in the workplace is professional behavior? Is this in compliance with our policies and acceptable within our desired corporate culture?**

Take your hints from the answer. If your boss is bluffing, that question will put them into a very awkward position (by design) and they will likely backpaddle ("Oh, I didn't mean that way ...").

If they are confirming it ("Sorry bub, that's just the way it is"), it's time to start looking. That's a not a place you want to work for.